# How to write a big number(whole and fraction part) with a single numeric literal using E-notation in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, numbers

I have a number which I want to assign a variable. But I want to use the shorter way (i.e. using e character)

```
let num = 1000000000.000001;
```

Possibly way, I could have both whole and fraction parts. but is there any way I can write in a single line?

```
let wholeNumPart = 1e9;
let fractionNumPart = 1e-6;
let num = wholeNumPart + fractionNumPart;
```

Comment: `let num = 1e9 + 1e-6`

Comment: You can use `1e9+1e-6` directly I guess?

Comment: I don't want to sum the both parts. I want to save it as a single value.

Comment: Once you sum them it will be a single value.

Comment: `1e9 + 1e-6` **is** one value. I suspect you mean "one numeric literal," but that's not what your question said. The answer is: No, there's no way to write that with a single numeric literal using E-notation (at least, none shorter than just writing it longhand as you have at the beginning above).

Comment: There is but, it's longer in e notation.

Comment: @Keith - LOL, I literally just edited it and saw your comment. :-D

Comment: Thanks @T.J.Crowder for more clarity. Yeah, it is not possible in a single numeric literal. Question title update BTW.

Comment: Using exponential notation you have `1000000000000001e-6`, which is 2 char longer. That's what it is.

Answer (score 3):

As the commenters pointed out, you can use `1e9 + 1e-6` directly, but no, there's no way to write that with a single numeric literal using E-notation — at least, not a way that's *shorter* than the long-hand way you've shown at the top of your question. You could use `1000000000000001e-6`, but that's longer than `1000000000.000001`.

That said, if you write `1e9 + 1e-6`, the JavaScript engine may well do the addition during the parsing stage (or other early stage) rather than waiting until the code is executed, as both parts are numeric constants. That's not an uncommon thing to do.